# download file with multiple connections

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hi i want to download *a file* with *multi java.net.Socket 's*.
I can get file with basic GET request :

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverName, 80);
DataOutputStream bw = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
bw.writeBytes("GET " + requestFileName + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
bw.writeBytes("Host: " + serverName + ":80\r\n\r\n");
bw.flush();

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

OutputStream dos = new FileOutputStream(indexFileName);
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    dos.flush();
}
dos.close();
socket.close();
```

This works perfectly but not sufficient because i wish to use multi sockets.
I can get Header with requesting HEAD so i can get only *Content-Length*
Now my plan is create threads with using this code. For instance if i want to download a file with 3 threads ; i will divide Content-Length by 3 and will download with 3 three thread. (0-99) + (100-199) + (200-299) = 300 for 300 bytes
then i will join parts but i could not find a way to parallel file download. Do i just need to change below part ?

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
    dos.flush();
}
```

or try to request from server with range of file size ?
For example

- GET 0-99 bytes of a.dat and put it into a.dat.part1
- GET 100-199 bytes of a.dat and put it into a.dat.part1
- GET 200-299    bytes of a.dat and put it into a.dat.part1

Comment: There isn't as much point to this as you might think. The network isn't multi-threaded. NB Don't flush inside loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the target HTTP server supports it, if I were you, I would:

1. Launch an initial request of type `HEAD` to get only the headers such as the `Content-Length` of my file not its actual content.
2. Then according to the `Content-Length`, launch one request per thread of type `GET` with the HTTP header [**Range**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) properly set to get a sub part of your file knowing that `Range: bytes=0-99` will give the `100` first bytes. Please note that the excepted HTTP code would then be `206` instead of `200` indicating that you received a partial content.
3. Then finally rebuild the file using [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to be able to write the content of the file at a given position, knowing that you can rely on [`setLength(long newLength)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength-long-) to create an empty file with a target size in order to be able to write the content of the file concurrently using a dedicated instance of `RandomAccessFile` for each thread.

Comment: You would also need to synchronize access to the file among the multiple threads -- assuming each thread is writing its own portion (and otherwise, you might as well use `FileOutputStream`). That is, if you have a single instance of the file, there will only be one file pointer. Each thread will be doing `seek` to set the file offset followed by `write`. It wouldn't do to interleave those operations among multiple threads.

Comment: thank you very much its working , 1 additional question , i am downloading only text file ,Do i really need to use RandomAccessFile  , or i can to put parts togetget via string concat in one file ?

Comment: Yes it is still needed to #1 avoid managing the encoding by storing your file content as bytes like a binary file and #2 to avoid keeping the content of your entire file into memory which could lead to OOME

Comment: Btw @NicolasFilotto is there any  GET command to get only the body part.I can get only Header with using HEAD command , is there a command like BODY. Because i put split parts together with RandomAccessFile class but it also puts Header info to the file (for example : if i download file with 3 threads , i am getting 3 header info in my file) or i need to eliminate them manually while processing input stream.

Comment: AFAIK no there is no such requests, the headers are needed to describe the body content